# network-manager no longer working after uninstalling wicd

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wicd

In trying to fix my network connection issues, I (tried to) install `wicd` (using `sudo apt-get install wicd`, intending to use it instead of `network-manager` (or whatever the default is). This seemed to work until I rebooted, at which point I was unable to connect to any networks although I could see them in `wicd`. So, I then uninstalled `wicd` (with `sudo apt-get remove wicd`) in an attempt to go back to the setup I had before.

Now, the default network setup no longer works either, and it seems that I have no way left to connect to a network. Specifically, it says 'device not ready' under Wi-Fi Networks. How can I fix this?

[image: image of device not ready]

(I have been trying to use `synaptic` package manager to download `network-manager` from offline, but I didn't have `synaptic` installed before this happened so I wasn't able to get that to work.)

For context: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04, haven't updated it since I installed it (as a dual boot) about 1 year ago. Never updated the OS, or downloaded many packages due to the aforementioned internet connection issue. Fairly new to Ubuntu - sorry that I seem to have messed up my OS. :(

Edit: here's the output from the wireless-info script: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25535333/

Comment: `network-manager` is the name of a software package, not an actual command as such - you should probably start at [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Thanks! I've run wireless-info and added the output above. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: You must remove network-manager to get wicd to work, or vise-versa. Both the network-manager & wicd can not work together. Please refer the URL https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse
Thanks
Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this problem now, so I'm answering my own question: `sudo service network-manager restart` worked for me. If I remember correctly it only worked for the first time when I ran it twice in a row. After that, I restarted my computer and the network-manager applet in the top bar was working again. After restarting, I had to run `sudo service network-manager restart` again to get the internet to actually work.